# Autocompletion in FlashDevelop doesn't work in included files

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flashdevelop

Why doesn't autocompletion work for function's local variables in included *.as files? For example:

Main.mxml:

```
<fx:Script>  
<![CDATA[
  include "code.as";     // or <fx:Script source="code.as"/>, doesn't matter  
]]>  
</fx:Script>
```

code.as:

```
import mx.controls.Button;
var foo:Button = new Button();
foo.   <---- autocompletion is working here

function myFunc() {
  var bar:Button = new Button();
  bar.   <----- doesn't work
}
```

Comment: could you please share some more code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Autocompletion will only work if a code class was imported, or if a class extended an .as class. **Has to be a Class**. When you use *'include code.as'*, code.as is not a class, its basically just a collection of variables, imports and functions, so autocomplete cannot access it like a class.

The **code-behind pattern** is similar to what your doing (seperating logic from the mxml), and allows for atuocompletion. To use it:

1. Create an Actionscript class that
   extends an MXML control that you
   want to use e.g. HBox or UIComponent
2. Put all of you logic within this
   Actionscript class.
3. Then create an MXML class that
   extends the Actionscript class.

Code completion will work in your new custom MXML class for accessing public/protected variables and functions.

Comment: Code-behind pattern doesn't make sense in my case. I've chosen to include code as a form of multiple inheritance. I even interfaced the public functions but still FlashDevelop can't find those functions for autocomplete. Pretty annoying, especially after using Sublime which autocompletes *everything*.

Comment: Hey Glenn. Would you not be better off putting the extra code in Class files or even Static utility files? But I know what you mean about trying to get multiple inheritance.

Comment: It's hard to explain why I'm using includes without writing an essay, but its basically providing a core "engine" to my view classes so they all interface with the data model the same way. Say, for instance, that flex was abysmal at cleaning up display objects. Well, I've added a "destructor" function to the included file so I can clean it classes that *I* know are destroyed so they don't keep rendering in the background while the garbage collector faffs about ignoring them. Small example, but there's lots of little things that need to be repeated across a couple hundred classes.